# reading from a file in a yii2 view

Tags: php, yii2

I have a standalone page under `views/site/test.php` that is supposed to read from a `txt` file, which I placed in `temp/test.txt` (temp and views in the same directory), so I used `$settings = fopen("../../temp/test.txt", "r");`

This always returns `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` as an error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, it seemed quite straightforward.

Comment: Verify that the file is on the server then try hard coding the entire path to start to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Yii::$app->basePath` for getting file contents like this.

```
$settings = fopen(Yii::$app->basePath."/temp/test.txt", "r");
```

Comment: still returns the same error. Just so I'm getting it right: basePath returns the path where the MVC folders are located?

Comment: May be: $settings = fopen(__ DIR __ . "/../../temp/test.txt", "r"); ? (with no space before and after word DIR